# What is the easiest way to count down 60 minutes?

Tags: time

I just saw this video, where three people were sat down in a garage space, each had to press a button after 60 minutes. 
I wonder what could be useful techniques to get as close as possible to 1 hour, without any clocks?

In the video they used the chair, and what they have had on them to stay in count.
Also, what could be a way to make it say 5 hours without getting insane?

The video:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=asFITwxXbGw

Comment: Are you asking about getting the duration correct, or about keeping count of the number of elapsed minutes?

Answer (score 1):

Well if clocks aren't allowed how about going old school and using an hour glass,
seems like a good hack for this problem.

You could even extend it for 5 hours by turning the glass upside down once an hour is complete, do this 4 times and you've successfully wasted 5 hours :p.

Answer (score 1):

1. Before the exercise, determine your resting heart rate.
2. Find a nice, restful spot and sit/lie there.
3. Count the time using your heart rate.

Answer (score 0):

Count to 3,600 at a steady pace.

1 Mississippi

2 Mississippi

...

60 x 60 = 3,600 = the seconds in an hour.

Answer (score 0):

Practice:

- Set an alarm for 1hour.
- Read or do some other activity.
- After a few times, try to predict.
- Keep going. You will get it.

I am a teacher. I do this all the time. 1 hour classes (but some-times I get it wrong).

Comment: So you in other words your brain gets practice for estimating an hour over a thousand examples per year. As a result, you got better at it. - Not as helpful for the rest of us that don't get that practice a thousand times a year.

Comment: You won't get good at anything without practice. However some practice will be better than others.